# How to know if environment variable was successfully set (Mac)

Tags: java, variables, unix, environment

Trying to set my JAVA_HOME environment variable to the location of my JDK. 
`ls -l 'which java'` returns `lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Nov  9 13:31 /usr/bin/java -> /System/.../java`

so I assume `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java` is the correct location of my JDK. So all I should do is write `export JAVA_HOME=$(/System/.../java)`.

Upon doing this, I get a massive output:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

Which looks like some kind of help on the usage of the `java` command. Was my export successful or not? Is JAVA_HOME now set to the location of my JDK?

Comment: You pointed the JAVA_HOME variable at the Java binary, not the directory where java executables exist

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to make this permanent, you must edit the `~/.bash_profile` file in your mac. In that file, type the export command you put above.

To check if it succeeded, in your terminal type `echo $JAVA_HOME` and look at the output. That will tell you what the current environment variable is set to for $JAVA_HOME.

Also, the `which` command just looks for the executable of `java`, not where the SDK is stored. You need to find where java was installed on your machine. For me, mine is this:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

And this will update automatically when a new version of java is installed.

Comment: Doesn't work. Here's what I did:
`> open ~/.bash_profile` (this didn't even work before I did `touch ~/.bash_profile`)
Then I wrote `export JAVA_HOME=$(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home)` in it and saved it.
Then I did:
`> echo $JAVA_HOME`
Nothing.

I got the new path by writing: `usr/libexec/java_home`

Answer (score 0):

To find out what your JAVA_HOME should be, you should be able to execute from the terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

If you have installed Oracle's Java and have the Java applet in your system preferences, this application will return the correct path to use as JAVA_HOME.

You can add this to your .bash_profile file either using the raw path returned, or there are some ways you can execute a command and assign the std-out response to a variable. e.g.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

I have on my system some applciations (UnrealEngine) that looks at the raw environment and consequently does not understand a JAVA_HOME set this way so I've had to hard code mine.

If the above does not apply, note that JAVA_HOME must point not at the java executable, not at the folder that contains the java executable, but one folder back, such that `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` is the path to your java. If you have set it up correctly you can execute

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

to see your java version.

---

Note that JAVA_HOME is supposed to be the path to the base folder of the default java installation.

'/usr/libexec/java_home' is NOT (or should not be) the path - or even a symlink - to a java installation - it is a program that returns via stdout, the path to a configured default java installation.

As such, you should either wrap it in backticks, or $(), as this causes bash to execute the contents of the parenthesis, and assign the stdout of that, to JAVA_HOME.

At least, this is how the Oracle JDK sets things up on OSX. If `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` works I do not understand how, unless that path is a symlink, and that seems wrong.

Comment: You last command generates: `-bash: /bin/java: No such file or directory`. Does this mean I need to reinstall Java?

Comment: What you said worked for me by removing the `$` and parenthesis from the `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` command, instead writing `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home` .

Comment: If you execute from terminal /usr/libexec/java_home does it return an error? OR a path? or nothing? As this tool is used to switch between Java instances using the Oracle Java system preferences applet, it might not be present at all if an Oracle JRE or JDK has not been installed. I.e. the bundled OSX Java might not have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

With Yosemite, you can add environment variables via properties list or *plist*.
    For example, ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>DGG.Environment</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>sh</string>
            <string>-c</string>
            <string>
launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME $(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
launchctl setenv M2_HOME /Users/dgg/JavaTools/apache-maven-3.3.9
launchctl setenv M2 /Users/dgg/JavaTools/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
launchctl setenv MAVEN_OPTS "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
            </string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

After a change to the plist file, run this from a shell to load the change:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.plist
```

Note that the multiple values within the `<string>` tags all execute correctly but I couldn’t get this method to work to modify the $PATH variable so I just did it in my .bash_profile to add $JAVA_HOME/bin and $M2 to the path.  I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but this works.

hope that helps,

dgg